# Can’t login on twitter with ParseTwitterUtils anymore

Tags: android, twitter, parse-platform, twitter-oauth

I am stuck on the most simple thing. I had implemented twitter log in and it used to work, now something looks broken. When simply doing

```
ParseTwitterUtils.logIn(this, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(final ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
               App.toast(e);
            }
});
```

It asks for my credential, then keeps waiting and waiting, for a minute or so, until I get

```
ParseRequestException: i\o failure
cause: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
```

I am 100% sure of the tokens used when initializing, and I am pretty sure of the settings in the developers page (I have a Facebook page, like http://www.facebook.com/mypage , as both the callback URL and the website URL).

What else?

I am using `com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.5`, but the same goes for `com.parse:parsetwitterutils-android:1.10.3`.